# CanvasJS rectangle spanning over mutliple DataPoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvasjs

Good day,

I would like assistance in drawing two rectangles that would span over multiple predefined DataPoints as in the attached image.

Here is a [link](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-candlestick-chart/) to code example.

[CanvasJs Candlestick Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dozoT.png)

Comment: How does your current code looks like?

Comment: @m4n0 I updated the post to include a link to a code example.